# how to check jsonresult output whether it is fail or success mvc

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonresult

I have JsonResult method given below  in a controller ..

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> Approve(string Decision, string Comments, string DeptCharged, string AcctCharged)
    {
        JSonOutPut jOut = new JSonOutPut();
         .......
         .......
         ......
        ........

         if (isApproved)
         {
                jOut.Status = "Success";
         }
         return Json(jOut);
    }
```

I am calling above method in another Method i.e ActionResult in a same controller like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Mapprove(string Id)
{

  JsonResult jsonApprovals = await Approve( null, null, null, null);
  // here i need to check the status of jsonapprovals 
  //if it is success i need to do some data changes....
}
```

Here I need to check the status of **jsonApprovals** whether it is fail or success.. how can i check the status of **Jsonapprovals**

Comment: `(JsonOutPut(jsonApprovals)).Status` did not worked?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
JsonResult jsonApprovals = await Approve( null, null, null, null);
JSonOutPut resultset  = jsonApprovals.Data as JSonOutPut;
if(resultset !=null)
{
  // do here what you want
}
```